# Poco HTTP (WebSocket) connections not accepted when there's outstanding TX queue

Tags: websocket, poco-libraries

O/S: Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit Linux server

Poco: 1.6.0-all

I have a WebSocket server built upon Poco's ServerSocket, ThreadPool, HTTPServer, RequestHandlerFactory, etc.

Symptom:
If there is any data still "stuck" in the TX queue (slow client and/or line), the handleRequest (callback function) would not get callled (by Poco), resulting in incoming HTTP (WebSocket) connections not being accepted. To be clear, the TCP connection is accepted (verified using telnet), but Poco wouldn't call handleRequest to complete the HTTP (WebSocket) handshake.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Output from netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0 248544 192.168.1.4:80        192.168.1.225:55447     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0 248544 192.168.1.4:80        192.168.1.225:55446     ESTABLISHED
tcp       62      0 192.168.1.4:80        192.168.1.225:55449     ESTABLISHED
tcp       62      0 192.168.1.4:80        192.168.1.225:55450     ESTABLISHED
tcp       62      0 192.168.1.4:80        192.168.1.225:55448     ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Are there any mutexes in your request handler factory and are you doing anything that may block for an extended period of time in the handler constructor? 

I suggest you run in debug, put a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/TCPServerDispatcher.cpp#L107) and see what happens from there.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. It was a mutex in my code causing the contention.